# map an array with objetcs with same key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encountered a little issue when I'm trying to map on an array, which contents many objects.
I want, with a Switch, return only when my object has a key defined.
Ex:

```
              if (d['Niveau sonore']) {
                console.log(d['Niveau sonore']);
                return d['Niveau sonore'];
              }
              return '';
            })}
```

But the problem, is in my array I have many objects with the same key 'Niveau sonore' for example, and I just want to return only one value.
How can I do that, I thought with Lodash it was possible but I did not succeed.
If you have a tip ;) thank you very much.

[image]

```json
[
  { "Notice": "Oui" },
  { "Livré avec": "Notice, Cordon d'alimentation d'eau, Cordon d'évacuation d'eau, Cordon d'alimentation électrique" },
  { "Livré avec": "Notice, Cordon d'alimentation d'eau, Cordon d'évacuation d'eau, Cordon d'alimentation électrique" },
  { "Type d'installation": "Full intégrable: le bandeau de commande est entièrement dissimulé dans la tranche de la porte. Ainsi, le lave-vaisselle tout …" },
  { "Type de produit": "Lave vaisselle tout intégrable" },
  { "Couleur": "Tout intégrable" },
  { "Type d'installation": "Tout encastrable avec panneau de commande invisible" },
  { "Niveau sonore": "silencieux 46 dB" },
  { "Niveau sonore": "46 dB silencieux" },
  { "Classe énergétique": "A++" },
  { "Poids net": "35.5" },
  { "Largeur produit (cm)": "59.8" },
  { "Hauteur produit (cm)": "82" },
  { "Profondeur produit (cm)": "57" },
  { "Longueur développée": "218" },
  { "Poids brut": "37.6" },
  { "Largeur": "Lave vaisselle 60 cm" },
  { "Niveau sonore": "Silencieux" },
  { "Profondeur": "Entre 56 et 59 cm" },
  { "Garantie": "24" },
  { "Fabriqué en": "Pologne" },
  { "Flèche énergétique": "Classe_Energetique_VERT_APP" },
  { "Disponibilité des pièces détachées (données fournisseur)": "Pendant 10 ans" },
  { "Référence constructeur": "DIFP66B+9 EU" },
  { "Marque": "INDESIT" },
  { "Fiche conformité UE (ne pas supprimer)": "Fiche d'information disponible sur la page du produit sur boulanger.com ou auprès d'un conseiller" }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Which one should be returned as there are many objects with the same key? Do you want to return first object with desired key? And also you are mapping an array so in return you will get desired array and not just one object. Also by your method, you will get in result an array of multiple empty strings ( that is :- "" ) and few strings which corresponds to the desired key.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have an array of objects where you want to retrieve the first object of that array that matches a condition correct?

Comment: Yes for the return '' it's because I have not processed yet to the end of logical.

Comment: But for my expected, I wanted display the most completed but first if I can get one and after I'll can  work on which one is the most relevant.

Comment: can you paste your data in the question ? not a screenshot

Comment: Sure I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your array of objects by using something like

```
yourArray.filter(obj => obj["Niveau sonore"] !== undefined)
```

This will give you a new array where only the objects with that key are present.

If you want to find the first item and extract it from the array use  [array find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method like so:

```
yourArray.find(obj => obj["Niveau sonore"] !== undefined)
```

You can have a look at the solution in this [Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=58&ssc=72&pln=58&pc=20#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAsAKFwbxgCIA5EKAS2AFMiAuYgeQFcKiYBfAGlwOIBkKANwBOAS5gIh1YPWJlKNLjADCIEXHDwA5AgA2FALbUwySlrjbqCZsrUaL2sUITBmSCo%20u3V6zWB19IxMzTwCxPRkoEQoAR2ZaTh48HHwiQVEJKRk5UnIqajs-RyDjUw8vGyKHAMtnV3dzWqsq3xrAgzLQrQiomPjE7l5U4gAVAE8AB2odCkhkPT0KsFyAMWZFmDmoMQBzEQQAI0iGSJhDhDA4b3gZ0ENDS%20uYamgX0woAC5FqLvgKCAQIwbCSISAwJYwaKXYAACxmz0hk3UUGoADoYABBOZA5RnJbSAC0LgBEGoixmUBAzFggDICdhDFKEIgTaa3GCTEQgOCsKC5fjZGAkwHks5UmlbUx7A7HQbJPhENQbajMES5UbU2DbaVHSIM%20UjFlTBHaHELJZNdWa97ABDQGVnbLADmXMA3Z73R5XGZzIQAiiy-XDZkkYQ3CDgdS0BhEIGRMDACgqgAeMAALAA2eAAISDTPkYZsMAjYCjuUzOeLFHjiZTeYVKiWIpgYjdIl2YkoA1ymIA1L364aAAogChwCAwN18mMAZgArGi54PmQL2yqRByuTyKLAABTAQwASlyc4AnGiABzL4gACRsqNVm%205vJg%206PuQvACZr0Qh1yAGbgNcj6cs%20O6vgex4xnOADsP78OAuwJI%20cDOOSICTJMYjRsQn4AIxXkkwbECOY4TocIg0rkM4wWiGbwQga6qvygrCmSFIwBmAAMMAHj%20obSEWJZljGADK1YmLWzDJj%20f4gIB3rMTGACipg-DAc5ZtQsBnrxhg-gA4oxlyUDhRCfmmP6rEc-TMBIJi5COeggLsbpWXonxwjMrbUO2nZxAkuSNnaZIAPqqb5uzaQF1ChQAaspABKoyhZiQ5Dj%20AAiALImAAbVjuoKvByXw0BOqHIHC2ETru-hgNVMCAaqeUiqqUEkSYYKwHhPGXBAP6JWI-5iD8CZ3OA9rMMAD5qjGmUAJKrEOGYZtmvanjAykAKo-gAsox3YxvNJCZcponzaMVlUPCvHgIBIiGIVMBbcpr5ui6E4QMwmExMYIjtUQqzXSacz3Y8TT-BAuUBmcX0bkiCBRfAzBPtusBw%20c1JLGAUUiGi9wwNSkjfSInzldozABKAkDUNWkRqkRKQALrDNTbz-tWqIiAJNzoIgyBohzehc7uICHAAVmgAB8hMSxgpCFijwk-EQTMwAAhKg6CU9cHNunAh64GzsB63APNFnzSAIILcxwKLEvS7L4vy%20bSuRiraua9r3p69QBtGxNICRGizm7LuQtc67hs4GzQfoqH4e21HQA)

Let me know if that is what you want and have any questions regarding it

Comment: condition could possibly be shortened to `('Niveau sonore' in obj)` or `obj.hasOwnProperty('Niveau sonore')`

Comment: It works fine your solution :) I have to work with that now, but I have well my newArray

Comment: Happy to help and you should shorten the solution as mentioned by @DustInCompetent